# Code or algorithm for the built-in function SavitzkyGolayMatrix

Tags: image-processing, filtering, smoothing

Does anyone know the algorithm that the function [`SavitzkyGolayMatrix`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SavitzkyGolayMatrix.html) implements?
Unusually, the help page does not spell out an explicit formula or the algorithm used. I am interested in the 2D case and would at least like to know the algorithm that calculates

```
SavitzkyGolayMatrix[{m, m}, {3, 3}, {0, 2}]
SavitzkyGolayMatrix[{m, m}, {3, 3}, {2, 0}]
SavitzkyGolayMatrix[{m, m}, {3, 3}]
```

for general positive integer `m`, to implement it in Matlab.

Answer (score 8):

```
GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions@SavitzkyGolayMatrix
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. If only I could figure out what this code is doing (and the corresponding code for `iSavitzkyGolayMatrix`)...